# SQL Server Compact data loss after closing application

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm working on an application which has a SQL Server compact database (I created the database in Visual Studio Server Explorer).

Now every time I open the app it goes well and I can insert records and retrieve them as well, but they disappear as soon as I close my app.

Why is that? Is there any option I've missed to configure?

Comment: Do you have connections not closed (or worst, transactions not committed)?

Comment: Oh I forgot to say that i'm using LinqToSql method (.dbml) and there is no opening and closing in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a little issue with name change :) thanks anyway